# MongoDB export to CSV the results of an aggregate unwind query?

Tags: json, mongodb, csv, robo3t, database

I'm getting an 'error validating settings: query  is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}' when trying to output my query to CSV.

My query is: 
     `'dev_experts:{$aggregate([{$unwind:"$expertise"}])}'`

How do I "unmarshal" that? I've run the query through Robomongo and I can see the results I want to export, but I can't export them through there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks very similar to this issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435512/mongoexport-error-cannot-unmarshal-string

Comment: Hi Pierre. Yes, it is the same type of issue, but I'm wouldn't know how to apply that situation to a query of this kind. Any tips? :)

Comment: So you want to get the output in Go and write the result to csv?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this query syntax, though I'm not an Robomongo expert ;)

`db.dev_experts.aggregate([{$unwind:"$expertise"}]);`

cf https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/ for more infos.

Comment: That works fine in Robomongo for a query, as in I can view the result of it, but I'm then looking to export the result of that to a CSV.

Comment: Use mongoexport in a terminal, type :

`mongoexport --username x --password x --host x --db mydb --collection dev_experts --query '{dev_experts:{$aggregate([{$unwind:"$expertise"}])}' --type=csv --fields id,expertise --out "./myfile.csv"`

Comment: Still reports that it cannot unmarshal string into Go value type of map[string]interface {}